# Add another step to css animation

Tags: css, animation

I have the following, which works nicely, but this is my first time trying css animation. How can I add another step in the animation? What I want to do is have message one either fade out or disappear and message two pop in then scroll out so it forms a nice loop.

```
<style style="text/css">

    .scroll-left {
         height: 50px;  
         overflow: hidden;
         position: relative;
         background:black;
         color: white;
         border: 1px solid white;
         font-size: 32px;
         font-style: italic; 
    }

    .scroll-left p 

     {
         position: absolute;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         line-height: 50px;
         text-align: center;

         /* Starting position */
         transform:translateX(100%);

         /* Apply animation to this element */  
         animation: scroll-left 8s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes scroll-left {
        0%   
        { 
             -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
             -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
             transform: translateX(100%);       
         }

         100% 
        { 
         -moz-transform: translateX(2%); /* Browser bug fix */
         -webkit-transform: translateX(2%); /* Browser bug fix */
         transform: translateX(2%); 
        }
    }
</style>

<div class="scroll-left">
    <p>
        <span style="color:#841214">Message One</span>  
        <!-- Message Two -->
    </p>
</div>
```

I realize I need to utilize different steps at different keyframe %s, but I'm not sure how it works when more than one item is to be animated in the same area.

I tried this to make the first message fade out :

```
@keyframes scroll-left 
    {
        /* Move it left */
        0%   
        { 
             transform: translateX(100%);       
         }

        /* Stop It */
        25% 
        { 
            transform: translateX(0%); 
             opacity:100;
        }

        /* fade out */
        40% 
        { 
             visibility: hidden;
             opacity:0;
             transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
             transform: translateX(0%); 
        }

        100%
        {
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity:0;
            transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
            transform: translateX(0%); 
        }
    }
```

But it just disappears and doesn't fade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify a start and finish value for any property you want to animate. In this case, `opacity` should be all you need.

```css
.scroll-left {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.scroll-left p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Starting position */
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */
  -moz-animation: scroll-left 5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: scroll-left 5s linear infinite;
  animation: scroll-left 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
  /* Move it left */
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  /* Stop It */
  25% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  /* fade out */
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-left">
  <p>
    <span style="color:#841214">Message One</span>
    <!-- Message Two -->
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay this is a lot simpler than I was making it out to be. For a second item, I just need to position them z-wise so they are in the same spot and animate it, correct?

Comment: Yeah, don't overcomplicate it. Don't add too many properties, focus on one thing at a time.